# HTTP Basic Auth with Nginx on a url that doesn't exist as a directory

Tags: nginx, server, .htpasswd, basic-authentication

Trying to use Nginx to password protect

mysite.com/admin

the thing is here that I'm using a web framework, and /admin is just another configured route in the system NOT a real directory

when I configured the site with:

```
location /admin {
    auth_basic "Administrator Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/.htpasswd;
}
```

and generated the htpasswd file, when I try to access the /admin, I get presented with login prompt, and it works great. But now any time I access the path, I get a 404 Not Found from Nginx itself

Anything I should do differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> and /admin is just another configured route

You can put configuration for that route in block like this

```
location /admin {
    auth_basic "Administrator Login";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.com/.htpasswd;
    .
    <your route configuration>
    .
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but in not sure what to put in place of <your route configuration> (I simply just don't know what your referring too)

Comment: can you comment that http auth for some time and give me output for

curl -IL example.com/admin